# How to animate a character made by two objects? (noob question)

Tags: modeling, animation, objects

I don't like bothering with my questions and I'm sure there's some tutorial about this there but since English is not my main language I'm not sure which words I should search to find it so I hope you'll be patient with me. I'm sorry.

So the thing is that I had made a character and this character had some kind of eyes in his face as an individual object. Just moment ago I was learning how to make an armature and animate him when I realised that, obviously, my character's eyes weren't moving as the rest of the body. Then in order to solve this I set parent to character's body but it didn't work.

So my question is: How can I merge two objets in order to animate them as a single character?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to parent your eyes to your body nor to join your objects. The only thing you have to do is to parent the eyes to their corresponding bones.

First select the eye objects, then the armature, then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → Set parent to armature deform with empty groups.
Then with the eyes selected, switch to edit mode. For each eye, select its mesh, and in the `Properties Editor` → `Mesh Data` tab → `Vertex Groups` panel, select the bone weight you want to assign that eye to, and hit the `Assign` button.

Comment: in your second step, if you go to pose mode after the selection and pick a bone, you can parent the eye to a specific bone and not have to set up a vertex group for it.

Comment: It was easier than I thought. Thank you 2!